# Fetch all rows for each row in a database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a database with list of members. I execute a certain query it selects all members satisfying a condition. Then for each member in resultset, I want to send the details of all members generated in output and continue the loop until end of resultset. My current SQL query is:

```
if( $result || mysql_num_rows($result) != 0) 
{
    $string = "result";
    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
           while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
           {
                  $string .= "," . $row['latitude'] . "," . $row['longitude'];
                  $i = $i + 1;
           }

         **$registration_id = $r['user_id'];**
    }
}
```

This does not give me an intended result? Any loopholes or bugs in this?

Comment: So should we `imagine` or `visualize` your table schema? :$ Sorry can't read your mind...

Comment: The double while on the same `$result` fetching seems creepy...

Comment: why have you used two while loops $r under first while loop is not being used any where else what is it...

Comment: @bonCodigo The table schema is:
email | number | imei | device | latitude | longitude | userID

Comment: be aware that the `mysql_xx()` functions are deprecated. They are considered obsolete and insecure. It is recommended to switch to either the `mysqli_xx()` functions or the PDO library.

Comment: It's almost certain that the above code could be achieved with only one loop and only one SQL query if you used a SQL `JOIN`. However without seeing the code or the queries you're using, it's not possible to be more helpful.

Comment: After the resultset is created from the SQL query, the first while loops should iterate through the entire resultset, and while the pointer is pointing to first resultset, it should again get the entire resultset for that member. Then the outer while loop should go to next record, again generate the entire resultset for that member, and go on until end of recordset.

Answer (score 0):

The first `while` fetches the entire row as an array. The second `while` made no sense.

```
if( $result || mysql_num_rows($result) != 0) 
{
    $string = "result";
    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        $string .= "," . $r['latitude'] . "," . $r['longitude'];
            $i = $i + 1;

          //Send notification to that member
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try without first WHILE

```
if( $result || mysql_num_rows($result) != 0) 
{
$string = "result";

       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
       {
              $string .= "," . $row['latitude'] . "," . $row['longitude'];
              $i = $i + 1;
       }
      //Send notification to that member
}
```

Comment: After the resultset is created from the SQL query, the first while loops should iterate through the entire resultset, and while the pointer is pointing to first resultset, it should again get the entire resultset for that member. Then the outer while loop should go to next record, again generate the entire resultset for that member, and go on until end of recordset.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `foreach` PHP loop

Like This;
Query the database and build an array of the members given the specific  conditions and build the members array like this

```
$members = array(); // Intialize Empty Array
$sql = "SELECT member_name FROM .... WHERE ... "; // Ensure you're selecting one field here
while($result = $mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($sql)))
{
$members[]=$result['member_name'];//This is the members array we're adding members to
}
//Get Members Array Count
$member_count = count($members);
//Check whether members array is more than 0 
if($member_count != 0)
{
//Do for each loop to select profiles for each member in our array
foreach($members as $key)
  {
  $sql = " SELECT email,number,imei,device,latitude,longitude,userID FROM ... WHERE member_name LIKE '$key' ";
   while($result = $mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($sql)))
      {
        //print results here
        .
        .
        .
      }


  }
}
```